# What is the noisy white circle on my minimap?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Occasionally I'll see a white circle filled with what looks like static on my minimap, which will eventually disappear.

It usually doesn't last long, so I haven't had the time to see what it is - what exactly causes this to show up, and should I avoid it?

Comment: Perhaps it's one of those mobile radar jammers?
http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Jammer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing is a friendly scrambler on the map.

Any enemies that travel inside the static circle will have their radar jammed.

Comment: A friendly recon drone will also show a similar static circle around it, and it likewise jams nearby radar.

Answer (score 1):

We have portable items jammers, radar, and trophy in MW3 to cause a stationary static circle once deployed. The recon drone shows on the minimap with one of these circles on it, it is mobile, and it jams enemy radar in its proximity.